# Docker a framework-less Java REST API

Tags: java, docker, rest, dockerfile

I have a Java RESTful API project, not using any framework or project management like Maven or Gradle. It's just one .java file being compiled and run.

I have been tasked to Dockerize it, but cannot find any articles or tutorials showing how to do it in my case. All articles make use of Spring and Maven.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

P.S. I'm not using an IDE; I'm using VSCode and its Java Extensions.

Comment: There is some samples using the openJDK docker image as base. Have a look here: https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you actually only need a container with a JVM (or the relevant parts of it) and your one Java file.

### Building Java Application (Replace Maven)

The thing that you need to do different is the compilation/ packaging as you don't have Maven. But if you only have one `.java` file and no dependencies this is fairly straightforward. You could simply compile your application using `javac` and then run it using `java`.
Here a quick walkthrough for a HelloWorld application which would resemble your project: one `.java` file, no dependencies.

Application.java

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

#### Compilation

Use `javac` to get `Application.class`

```sh
javac Application.java
```

Optionally you could now create a `.jar` file for your application.

```sh
jar -cvf Application.jar Application.class
```

#### Run it

Once you have `Application.class` you can simply run it using `java`.

```sh
java Application
```

or for a `.jar` file

```sh
java -jar Application.jar
```

### JVM

So you can now build your Java application the only real question is which image you start your Docker image off. You need a `JVM` to run it and `javac` to build it, nothing else.
You could use pre-built images like [eclipse-termurin](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin?tab=description) then your Docker image would look something like this. I am using my little HelloWorld application here.

> Note: This is using Java 11, you will need to do some adjustments for later Java versions.

Dockerfile

```
# Multi-stage docker build
# this is the image we are using to build the docker image
FROM eclipse-temurin:11 as builder
# make a folder for the build
RUN mkdir /opt/build
COPY Application.java /opt/build/Application.java
RUN javac /opt/build/Application.java

# this is the actual production docker image
FROM eclipse-temurin:11
ENV APP_HOME=/opt/app
# make a folder for the application
RUN mkdir ${APP_HOME}
# copy the built application over from the builder image
COPY --from=builder /opt/build/Application.class  /opt/app/Application.class
# Not required for my application but your web server
# The next line exposes port 8080 (if uncommented)
# EXPOSE 8080
# this is run on docker run
CMD cd $APP_HOME && java Application
```

Using this Dockerfile you will then be able to to build the image (when you are in the directory of your Dockerfile)

```sh
docker build -t test/java .
```

And last but not least run it.

```sh
docker run --rm test/java
```

For your web server you would need to provide a port mapping using option `-p` like `-p 8080:8080` as well.

This will print

```
Hello World!
```

The relevant part is the `FROM`. There are many options out there.

1. Start from a OS image

You could start from a simple OS image like Ubuntu or Alpine Linux install a JVM using e.g. apt repository, binaries or whatever and then build your project and run it as shown above.

2. Start from pre-built image

There are small pre-built images with a JVM already ready for use out there e.g. [Eclipse-Termurin](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin?tab=description) or [OpenJDK](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk), some of which are actually outdated and you would need to choose the right tag for your desired java version. As explained on DockerHub for Eclipse Termurin you could also build your own JVM using **jlink** which might give you an even smaller container.

3. Distroless images

All those abovementioned options are actually bigger or smaller Linux distributions with a JVM running, but there also are [Distroless containers](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) which are quite small and there is no shell or other unnecessary stuff for your application installed.

There are also some best practices for building good Docker container which focus on areas such as security, image size, caching etc. so it is certainly worth exploring those, as the Dockerfile I have shown you is by no means production ready, but it works and will help you get started.

Comment: How would this docker setup expose port 8080 for use with the RESTful API?

Comment: Good point. You would need to add `EXPOSE 8080` as a command anywhere before the last `CMD`. Then in the run command add `docker run --rm --name my-container -p 8080:8080 test/java`. Check my edit in the Dockerfile.